# exporting MS word documents using codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, ms-word

exporting MS word documents using codeigniter any idea or tutorial on how to code? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control:  must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"mydocument_name.doc\"");

$output = $this->load->view("myreport", $mydata);
echo $data;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this for excel and word export data

first you make controller 
this like this

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Data extends CI_Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
     $this->load->view('data_page_view'); 
  }
  public function toExcel()
  {
     $this->load->view('spreadsheet_view');
  }
}
```

put a link from where you want to download in a view like this

```
<a href='data/toExcel'>Export Data</a>
```

and this may your view for excel data

```
    <?php         
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=exceldata.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    ?>
    <table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Important info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nadeem</td>
        <td>Ijaz</td>
        <td>Nothing really...</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

and this code for word data

```
    <?php         
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control:  must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"worddata.doc\"");
    ?>
    <table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Important info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nadeem</td>
        <td>Ijaz</td>
        <td>Nothing really...</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```