# Codeigniter - Export Database data in DOC format

Tags: codeigniter, ms-word, doc

I want to export data in my MYSQL Database into a DOC file using Codeigniter. 
My code is as follows:

view named 'profile_top_view.php' where anchor is declared as :

```
<?php echo anchor('welcome/todoc','Export Posts to DOC File') ?>
```

controller named 'welcome.php' has function :

```
 public function todoc() {
    $id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
    $this->mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;
    $filename = "POSTS";
    $data['member'] = $this->s_model->alldata($id);
    $this->load->view('export_posts_doc_view', $data, true);
    $this->index();
}
```

A view named 'export_posts_doc_view.php', where a table will be created for the DOC file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Exported Posts in PDF File</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control:  must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"posts.doc\"");
        ?>


        <div id="container">
            <h4>Posts</h4>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>title</th>
                    <th>content</th>
                    <th>group</th>
                    <th>video_url</th>
                    <th>pic_path</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>phone</th>
                    <th>email</th>
                    <th>yes_no</th>
                    <th>single-line-text</th>
                    <th>para_text</th>
                    <th>pdf_file_name</th>
                    <th>add_photo_name</th>
                </tr>
<?php
foreach ($member as $rows) {
    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['title'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['content'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['group'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['video_url'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['pic_path'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['phone'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['email'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['yes_no'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['single-line-text'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['para_text'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['pdf_file_name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['add_photo_name'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
            </table>

            <br> <br>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and also a model named 's_model.php', having function :

```
  function alldata($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('');
        $this->db->from('posts');
            $this->db->where('user-id',$id);
        $getData = $this->db->get();
        if($getData->num_rows() > 0)
        return $getData->result_array();
        else return null;
    }
```

If I keep that header there, then it is showing error as:

> No webpage was found for the web address:
>   http://www.my_ip.com/project/welcome/todoc

But, if I remove the same header, it shows the things echoed in the controller.
I have got that header from the following URL:
[exporting MS word documents using codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172461/exporting-ms-word-documents-using-codeigniter)

Can anyone please let me know what should I do with that?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Does it make a difference if you set the headers in the controller, before loading the view? Whenever I've used codeigniter to make an rss feed, pdf, etc, I always set the headers in the controller, not the view.

Comment: @Jeemusu It is showing error as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer,

I made few changes in my controller 'welcome.php':

```
public function todoc() {
        $id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $this->mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;
        $filename = "POSTS";
        $data['member'] = $this->s_model->alldata($id);      
        $this->load->view('export_posts_doc_view', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

see the code below i hope i will work for you

```
    function exportexcel()
    {
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); 

   /* change the content-type depends upon our requerment */

        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Sadhak.xls");

        header("Pragma: no-cache");

        header("Expires: 0");

    $table = "your content goes here";

    echo  $table;
    }
```